# Java GWT maps api v3 add click handler to Marker

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I used `addMarkerDoubleClickHandler()` and `addMarkerClickHandler()` for markers in gwt, but for google maps api v3 does not provide these functions. Can you help me with my problem ? What are the way in google api v3?

```
marker.addMarkerDoubleClickHandler(new MarkerDoubleClickHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using this [gwt-wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/) for google maps v3 it should be this:

```
Event.addListener(HasJso, "dbclick",new EventCallback() {
    @Override
    public void callback() {
    }
});
```

`HasJso` is the instance of your gwt-maps object.